# ROR: HTML and JSON both?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Scaffolding creates the controllers which have the Create/Update methods. These methods have rendering HTML and also JSON. I know HTML but I do not know what JSON is. Is it necessary to have JSON in there or I could take it out and still work with HTML rendering?

Here is the piece of code am talking about:

```
def create
  @judge = Judge.new(judge_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @judge.save
      format.html { redirect_to @judge, notice: 'Judge was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @judge }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @judge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not bothered about JSON you could simply do:

```
def create
  @judge = Judge.new(judge_params)

  if @judge.save
    redirect_to @judge, notice: 'Judge was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the JSON portion and still have it work fine.

[JSON](http://json.org/) is a popular format typically used for Javascript/API calls.